# Why CRUD Operations Using Ajax and Json for Django powered app is so slow?If being 7000 records is an issue, how can I improve it to seconds?

Tags: json, ajax, django, crud

I am performing operations on remote legacy MySQL database having about 7000 records.Currently, it's taking around 1.5 minutes for the Update / Delete / Create operation.I have also imported necessary files which is not included in Views.py below.

Is using dict() a problem? Should I use Rest? OR some other API. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Here is the code:

plugin.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ShowForm = function(){
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: btn.attr("data-url"),
        type: 'get',
        dataType:'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#modal-book').modal('show');
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#modal-book .modal-content').html(data.html_form);
        }
    });
};

var SaveForm =  function(){
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('data-url'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.form_is_valid){
                $('#book-table tbody').html(data.book_list);
                $('#modal-book').modal('hide');
            } else {
                $('#modal-book .modal-content').html(data.html_form)
            }
        }
    })

    return false;
}

// create 

$(".show-form").click(ShowForm);
$("#modal-book").on("submit",".create-form",SaveForm);

//update

$('#book-table').on("click",".show-form-update",ShowForm);
$('#modal-book').on("submit",".update-form",SaveForm)

//delete

$('#book-table').on("click",".show-form-delete",ShowForm);
$('#modal-book').on("submit",".delete-form",SaveForm)

});
```

Views.py

```
 # Fetching records with pagination

 @login_required()
 def book_list(request):
 books = AvailstaticCopy.objects.all().order_by('-row_date')
 page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

 paginator = Paginator(books, 144)
 try:
    books = paginator.page(page)
 except PageNotAnInteger:
    books = paginator.page(1)
 except EmptyPage:
    books = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

 context = {
 'books': books
 }
 return render(request, 'books/book_list.html',context)

@login_required()
def save_all(request,form,template_name):

data = dict()
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        books = AvailstaticCopy.objects.all()
        data['book_list'] = render_to_string('books/book_list_2.html',
        {'books':books})
    else:
        data['form_is_valid'] = False
  context = {
  'form':form
 }
 data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name,context,request=request)
 return JsonResponse(data)

# Create new record

@login_required()
def book_create(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AvailForm(request.POST)
else:
    form = AvailForm()
return save_all(request,form,'books/book_create.html')

# Update record

@login_required()
def book_update(request,id):
 book = get_object_or_404(AvailstaticCopy,id=id)
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AvailForm(request.POST,instance=book)
 else:
    form = AvailForm(instance=book)
return save_all(request,form,'books/book_update.html')

 # Delete Record

@login_required()
def book_delete(request,id):
 data = dict()
 book = get_object_or_404(AvailstaticCopy,id=id)
 if request.method == "POST":
    book.delete()
    data['form_is_valid'] = True
    books = AvailstaticCopy.objects.all()
    data['book_list'] = render_to_string('books/book_list_2.html',
    {'books':books})
 else:
    context = {'book':book}
    data['html_form'] = 
 render_to_string('books/book_delete.html',context,request=request)

 return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for giving me a hint.That worked! I have paginated queryset like this:

```
def save_all(request,form,template_name):

  data = dict()
  paginate_by = 144

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        books = AvailstaticCopy.objects.all().order_by('-row_date')
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(books, 144)
        try:
            books = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            books = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            books = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        data['book_list'] = render_to_string('books/book_list_2.html',
        {'books':books})

    else:

        data['form_is_valid'] = False
 context = {
 'form':form
 }
 data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name,context,request=request)
 return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, your problem is in server responses. In all views where you change server data (delete, update, create) you try return updated book list, but you do not paginate book queryset, and django template processor take a lot of time to prepare html with all books. I suggest you add function which will paginate queryset like this:

```
def get_book_page(request, books):
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(books, 144)
     try:
        books = paginator.page(page)
     except PageNotAnInteger:
        books = paginator.page(1)
     except EmptyPage:
        books = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return books
```

And wrap all book querysets in your views. Also it will be needed add to urls page number as get parameter (for example `/update-book/1?page=2`) because if you don't do it, it won't be work.